# Cocoa API for Disk Space Usage Breakdown

Tags: macos, cocoa, diskspace

I would like to be able to display a disk space usage breakdown chart similar to the one used in the System Information app built into Mac OS X (see image below). I've searched but have been unable to find an API which returns any detailed breakdown. The best I can find is the total disk space used.

As far as I can tell, the data in the screenshot (which actually looks incorrect in this example) is not calculated by sizing the default Music, Movies, Photos and Application folders. It does seem to add up the data used by specific file types.

[image: Disk Space Usage Mac OS X]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps they are using the Metadata APIs and customizing the search a bit?
That's what I had used in the past to get a breakdown of certain types...

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/SpotlightQuery/Concepts/Introduction.html